# Docker logs with log-driver

Tags: docker, logging, graylog, gelf

I am running a new container using the following command:

```
docker run -d --log-driver=gelf --log-opt gelf-address=tcp://<my_log_server> nginx
```

Looking at the documentation, this should send the logs to my_log_server, and if I run the *docker logs <my_container>* command I shoult **NOT** see any logs.
But actually I do, and I don't want this.

Do you have any idea why this is happening?

I'm testing it with *Docker version 20.10.8, build 3967b7d*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the docker documentation - https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/configure/

> When using Docker Engine 19.03 or older, the docker logs command is only functional for the local, json-file and journald logging drivers. Docker 20.10 and up introduces “dual logging”, which uses a local buffer that allows you to use the docker logs command for any logging driver. Refer to reading logs when using remote logging drivers for details.

Hope it clarifies.